# How can I make a popup appear at the top of the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I'm trying to make a password protected site, and I want the site to display a browser message saying "The site example.com requires a username and password" like I've seen on some sites but I can't figure out how to. I don't want a login form on the page, I want one to be displayed by the browser. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean basic auth, so the thing where you have to enter your user information, you have to implement that on your server. For that you can have a look [here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/09/24/nodejs-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api)